# Sudden gvfs error when issuing la command

Tags: 14.04, gvfs

I have started

```
la ~
```

with the output

```
ls: cannot access .gvfs: Permission denied
```

I've done quite a bit of googling but haven't found a solution. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: In which directory you have started `la`?

Comment: @A.B. in my home directory.

Comment: Than [edit] your question.